# button element onclick to run javascript function without JQuery

Tags: javascript

Why won't this give an alert?  I need to make it work without JQuery and with the "button" element since the button is being auto-generated.  It works if I put the javascript inside the quotes, but I want to call a function.

```
<button onclick='test()' >click</button>
```

**javascript**

```
function test()
{
alert('hi');
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nn90okdj/1/

Comment: [You code works as it is](https://jsfiddle.net/w1xqm5x6/1/). In your fiddle you've wrapped the code within `onload` handler, which excludes `test` from the global scope.

Comment: Your code is fine jsFiddle is acting weird. I had to wrap JS in script tags to get to work in jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nn90okdj/16/

Comment: Maybe a bit aside, but as a big fan of delegated events, I can insure you, that you can delegate events without jQuery as easily as with jQuery, you really don't need an inline handler.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle is being weird. Your code is fine.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onclick

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work right for me here.

```js
function test()
{
alert('hi');
}
```

```html
<button onclick='test()' >click</button>
```

Comment: That works inside of stackoverflow, but not in jsfiddle.  weird.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not working correctly because, `script` is getting loaded at top of the `html` page. It should be loaded at the `bottom` if you want to access the `DOM` element

- Click on the Javascript button
- Select `No wrap in body`
- It should work properly now

To rectify this.

[image: Javascript Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

The function `test` does not work in the `jsFiddle` environment because what you write in the `javascript` section is placed into the `window.onload` handler by `jsFiddle`.

If you do not want to change any settings, directly add to the `global` scope like here: https://jsfiddle.net/93a8rtaf/

```js
this.test = function () {
  alert('hi');
}
```

```html
<button onclick='test()' >click</button>
```